# Hi. I need to turn my data off for both sim cards in Moto gen2.

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I just received a huge bill for data usage. I want to know how to turn my data off on each simcard on my dual sim Motorola gen 2 phone. I want to use data when connected to wifi only.I don't know how to do this.
Please help......
Liz

Answer (score 0):

1. From the home screen, swipe the Status bar down.
2. Tap the Quick settings icon
3. Tap SETTINGS
4. Tap Data usage
5. Tap to toggle Mobile data ON (Then it will ask you to disable mobile data?)
   [image]
6. Tap OK.
7. The mobile data connection is now disabled.